Measuring sleep current and active current across multiple DUTS
I'm trying to measure sleep current (around 100uA) and active current (around 9A) across 3 DUTs.  I would like to use a single siglent SDM3065x DMM or some IC reporting ADC values. I found the INA191A1 for measuring the sleep current.  Is there a similar device to measure active current?

I'm assuming you're not going to use the same device as before because you want perhaps something that can potentially handle 9A. In that case, how about a big shunt resistor and measure the voltage drop across it?

correct. using different device.  so 2 questions, the INA191A1 is good for measuring sleep current in the range that I am looking for right (100uA)? Second, i could use a big shunt resistor but im trying to read the current on an analog line. How would I do that?
